# Rails3. Is there any way to separate javascript file for different controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I search around for quite some time but there's are no close solution for this.

For example,

I had generated 2 controllers: Articles, and Calendars.

There have been 2 javascript files also been generated according to these 2 controllers as:

calendars.js and articles.js.

The problem is, if they (2 files) all are included into application.js without any condition. i.e when I open articles/index action, the calendars.js has been imported on page

or when I open calendars/index action (or any action), the articles.js has been imported on page.

What I am looking for is a methodology to separate javascripts file according to the controller that they are belong to?

I also having the same question related to css files.

Thank you and Best regards,
Dat

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is only execute certain pieces of javascript on each controller (action). You can achieve that easily with this gem: https://github.com/intrica/rails_document_ready.

Comment: Thank you Arjan for your feedback. I will made some experiment of this GEM. But at the first glance, I doubt about using twitter-bootstrap-rails GEM along with this GEM. Anyway, I will definitely feedback.

Comment: It should be no problem. I used a similar construction with the twitter-bootstrap gem, before the rails_document_ready gem came to exist, and I experienced no issues. Both require jQuery, but apart from that have very different responsibilities and can easily be used to complement each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your index.html.erb file.

For the specific page where you want this js file add in your html file.

**<%= javascript_include_tag "articles" %>**

Comment: Thank you manish nautiyal. I had thought about your solution. But we also used gem twitter-bootstrap-rails. If you just include <%= javascript_include_tab "articles", it will missing the the bootstrap things. As I known so far, the GEM  bootstrap things can only be implemented with application level.

Answer (score 0):

I found paloma: https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma
I develop new Rails application for about 2 months with this gem, and it provide quite effective way to manage javascript.